# May I open a microsoft data connection file (.odc) created through PowerBI WEB with python?

Tags: python, powerbi

May I read a Microsoft data connection file (`.odc`) created through **PowerBI WEB** with python??
I have tried to use `pyodbc.connect` but I don't know how to build the Connection String